# Can I access Google drive docs without a Google acount?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I want my android app to access a specific acount [not the user's account] and download a file. Is this possible?

Comment: So you want to publicly host a file on Google Drive?

Comment: Yes I do at least for a specific app.

Answer (score 1):

To use google docs you need a google account.
This does not require you to have a **google mail** account.

With this URL you can make yourself a google account using your own email adres:
https://accounts.google.com/NewAccount?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2F%23&followup=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2F&service=writely&ltmpl=homepage

Good luck,

Thomas van Latum

Comment: I know this but I don't want to pry into the user's account for somthing public and It doesn't seem possible to sign all of the users into my account

Answer (score 0):

This is generally possible using [Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Service Accounts however may not be used directly from Android applications, as Android wouldn't be able to protect your private key file.

A workaround would be to have a web application yourself that queries the data from Google using a Service Account and only connecting to your web application from Android. How you make sure that only your client can access your web application is then however in your responsibility.

Comment: Can I create a service account using an android web view?

Comment: Can I create an ad hoc account for the user within the application?

Comment: The answer to both your questions is no.

Comment: Thanks this is a real time saver.

Comment: Is it possible for a very large amount of users to sign in through one account via an android app and access one account's drive? Is there a limit to contiguous use of one account?

Comment: From [Google's help](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33330): `Each Gmail account intended and designed for use by an individual user. If you have multiple users frequently accessing the same account from various locations, you may reach a Gmail threshold and your account will be temporarily locked down.`

Answer (score 0):

What I was looking for, namely freemium cloud services, is better served by Google appEngine or Azure or Amazon or Apple cloud Freemium deals etc. Note that these are usually easy to implement but there are many scaling issues that should affect the decision. Importantly there is high cost in moving from one cloud platform to another because the code is idiosyncratic and useless outside the specific cloud.